Is there a way to pass a param in a react route without using it in the url?
I want to make a route to a page that will change depending on what is stored in id. However, I also want the page URL to be entirely different from id. I currently have a working route: <Route path="/schedule/:url" element={<SchedulePage />} />. This properly sets the path to be "website.com/schedule/" + whatever is stored in url. Here is the issue: in my SchedulePage, I want to display information that I grab from id. The only way I can find to do so is with params, but I want to keep the id out of my url. How can I pass the id through the route as a param without including it in the url?
I tried changing the route to <Route path="/schedule/:url/:id?" element={<SchedulePage />} /> in the hopes that it wouldn't include the id, but that didn't work at all.
UPDATE:
I was able to find a solution with the help of STerliakov (See comments below to read our conversation.)
What I needed was the Mongoose function findOne(). Using this, I was able to do what I hoped to achieve; create a unique, user-defined String that fulfills the same purpose as _id (A unique anchor that can be used to find any one object.)

Why do you need that? If ID enumeration is a problem for you, then hiding it from attacker won't help: it will appear in your backend requests anyway, and anyone can open devtools. If you have some other concern, please state it explicitly. Otherwise the answer is "stop that and mitigate ID enumeration in some other way", there are plenty of solutions.

@STerliakov I am not trying to hide the ID for security, I am trying to avoid a page URL like "website.com/schedule/66llac0ba4da..." It is purely for the sake of shortening the URL as I want it to be easily read. You mentioned plenty of other solutions, would any of those apply with this clarification?

Hm, with this context the question is much better! Consider [edit]ing it into the question body. For this, the first thing that crosses my mind is using a slug instead of ID. Keep ID your primary key and add a unique indexes slug field. It works well if your entities have some kind of textual content: for example, an article could have it's title+date concatenated and normalized as a slug (make sure to add support for a random suffix in case of collisions!). Then you point to /articles/:slug page instead and add a minor modification server side to use slug for lookup.

I'm not sure what kind of object a schedule is in your q body, if it's some kind of an event - cool, you can use its name or something like name || iso8601(date) as a slug. If it's just some scheduled event without a human-readable label/title/whatever, perhaps its full datetime could work (again, do not forget about unique suffix in case of collisions).

@STerliakov Apologies for not including that context before, and thank you for responding! I understand that the ID needs to be unique, and I was hoping that it could be created by the user. For example, they would create an acceptable String that is required to be unique and the resulting page would have the same URL as what they entered. Adding a slug is definitely a solution, but I'd really like for the URL to be exactly what the user defined. Do you think it would be possible for the user's String to overwrite MongoDB's _id? Sorry if these are foolish questions, I'm still new to backend!

Hmm, if your users provide some unique ID that means something for them, why not use that as a slug and leave ID to your DBMS?

@STerliakov Apologies once again if I'm misunderstanding. I thought slugs create a shorter randomized string to ensure uniqueness, no? "website.com/schedule/user" becomes "website.com/schedule/user-hhu3i1" or something to that effect? If I can have the slug be exactly what the user inputs, I think that is my solution. Any clue how I can use Mongoose to select the specific schedule object from the slug? I was operating under the assumption .findById was the only way to get an object based off of a unique value. Thank you so much for bearing with me.

You have .findOne that allows for lookup on arbitrary fields. Slugs do not have to be randomized: they are often derived from other properties. So, if a user enters myevent, you have a choice: either require that no other schedule called myevent exists, or add a short random suffix yourself in case of collision. In the latter case users can provide "unique enough" names to rarely hit that. You can make it unique per user: .findOne({slug: 'myevent', user: curentUserId}). In both cases make sure to add appropriate indexes!

@STerliakov .findOne is perfect! This is exactly what I've been trying to achieve. I think I just needed someone to help me wrap my head around this whole process. I can't thank you enough for your help and your willingness to help a newbie out! I'll try to implement this right now.

By using the Mongoose function .findOne, you are able to use a unique value to find an object. By setting your user's chosen String to something like url, you can use the following code:
Schedule.findOne({url});

This effectively makes a value just like _id that can be used to find a specific object, however the url value must be unique. This was not an issue in my case as I wanted to use the value to generate unique page URLs anyways. I've learned a lot in the past two hours.
